# No Data holes with Mapfile / Python

Tags: gdal, nodata, mapfile

I am working with Python with GDAL and Mapfile and I used the following cmd line in order to remove NoData:

```
cmd = ["gdal_edit.py", src_img , "-unsetnodata"]
```

And then in my application with my mapfile I defined into my layer:

```
OFFSITE 0 0 0
```

In my app, I can see that the NoData is transparent, however I also have "no data holes" into my image.

[image]

With Gdalinfo, I have the 4 corners of my image, I need to differentiate the image and the NoData but I don't really know how to that. I thought to add a TIFF behind the image in order to cover the "no data holes" but do you have any better idea?

Comment: What is your NoData value? What pixel type is the raster? Do you have the trapezoid for the data area? If so you can use GDAL_Warp -dstnodata of any value that is valid for the data type but out of range for real data and -cutline of your polygon covering the data area. If you don't already have a data area polygon you can use GDAL_Calc to create a binary raster of data/nodata, convert raster to polygon, remove the wedges and dissolve for a home-made cutline data source.

Comment: My nodata value is 0 and I don't have the trapezoid of the data area I just have the corners (including the no data). Trying gdal_calc, keep you in touch cheers!

Comment: What is OFFSET used for? Or do you mean OFFSITE?

Comment: @user30184 My bad, I mean OFFSITE not OFFSET. I fix into my main message